# How to save sign up api response and pass the data in the response to profile screen

Tags: swift, api, save

In my app how do i save signup API response i.e userid,username,email,profile image and once sign up successfully it takes me to profile screen . How do i show the saved response in the respective field in profile screen controller. I am using alamofire for parsing and have also created signup data model. How can i save with swifty user defaults library

Comment: Hello, it seems that you should first learn about data storage. Try to google "raywenderlich alamofire tutorial", and "Getting Started with Core Data Tutorial".
Then show the data in UILabels for example

Answer (score 0):

You can use Database (Core Data, Realm, ...) or UserDefaults to store data.

Comment: Dont know sir as i am new to ios development

Answer (score 0):

You can use userdefaults for saving your username,userid,username,email. If you have profile image as url string, you can save it in userdefaults and call it on image in your profile screen too. If you have profile image as an image, may be you can cache it or save it in a singleton class. Storing process can be multiple so you have to choose it depending your business of app.

Comment: In api parsing i am passing email.text to email parameter and like wise so on how do i save email response for example and show it in my profile screen

Comment: May be you can check this out. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-save-user-settings-using-userdefaults. I wish that helps you.